# Syntax error in SELECT query inside PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a query inside a PDO script that checks if a record exists if it does the query should update the record and if it doesn't exist it should create a new one.

The column that should only exist once in the table is not an INDEX key (cannot make it unique right now) so it is not set as unique and I cannot use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

**I would like to use this queries logic below to make it work:**

```
   $stmt = $conn->prepare('IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `Table1` WHERE `code`= :code )
    UPDATE `Table1`
    SET `code_stat` = 2
    WHERE code = :code
ELSE
    INSERT INTO `Table1` (`code`,`code_stat`)
    VALUES (:code, 2 ) ' );

                $stmt->execute([
                'code' => $_POST['code']
                ]);
```

**The problem is when executing the query I get the following error saying there is a syntax problem:**

```
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE code= ? ) UPDATE Table1' at line 1
```

Comment: Rather than posting an identical question, edit your existing question with this new information.

Comment: I specifically stated in my question I cannot use on duplicate update, I just need help correcting the syntax error

Comment: @user3783243 there's no unique key so that won't work

Comment: @JenLarson why can't you add a unique key to `code`

Comment: I don't have control over the table structure right now, so using something like this is the best I can do

Comment: i see no other option than doing two queries, the select, then use the result to determine which 2nd query to run

Comment: Yes I agree, what can be added to my query to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add a unique key to the table, you can attempt an update first, and if that doesn't update any rows, do an insert. Something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `Table1` SET `code_stat` = 2 WHERE code = :code');
$stmt->execute(array(':code' => $_POST['code']));
if (!$stmt->rowCount()) {
    // no rows updated, so insert
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `Table1` (`code_stat`, `code`) VALUES (2, :code)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':code' => $_POST['code']));
}
```

Note that you may need to set the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` attribute to ensure that the `UPDATE` query returns 1 if it finds the row but the value doesn't change. You must set that attribute when you make the connection e.g.

```
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
```

Comment: I receive the error SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number, don't understand why

Comment: @JenLarson I did have a couple of typos. I presume you've fixed them. Which query gives the error?

Comment: @JenLarson note that you can't use `setAttribute` to set the `MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS` attribute, you need to set it on connection. See my update.

Comment: @JenLarson this code is running fine on my local PHP/MySQL server. Can you provide more info as to what problems you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a stored procedure to handle this, similar to the below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db.SP_NEW_CODE;
CREATE PROCEDURE db.`SP_NEW_CODE`(IN `in_code` INT)
BEGIN

  DECLARE numFound INT DEFAULT 0;
  SET numFound=(SELECT * FROM `Table1` WHERE `code`= in_code);

  IF (numFound=0) THEN
    INSERT INTO `Table1` (`code`,`code_stat`) VALUES (in_code, 2 );
  ELSE
    UPDATE `Table1` SET `code_stat` = 2 WHERE code = in_code
  END IF;
END;
```

From your code, simple execute CALL SP_NEWCODE(3);  (for example, where 3 is the appropriate code value).

Comment: I cannot use stored procedures at this time, it must be a query that checks for the record and based on those results does either an update or an insert, all using PHP

Comment: Then do a SELECT COUNT(code) AS code_count FROM Table1 beforehand and then determine whether to do an INSERT or UPDATE based on recordset['code_count']